# @Styles.Render & @Scripts.Render won't work in Empty MVC Visual Studio solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I create a Solution with an MVC 5 Template in VS 2015 - Bundling & Minification works fine.

If I create a Solution with an Empty Template with folders and core references for MVC - Bundling & Minification won't work.

These do not work in a Razor view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

(error: The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context).

I have tried installing the nuget package - but it doesn't help:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Any references in Google appear to apply to older versions, and the above nuget package.

How am I supposed add Bundling & Minification to a project that doesn't have it? Is there a different nuget package or something?

Comment: Does your web project have a reference to `System.Web.Optimization`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to ensure you have a reference to `System.Web.Optimization` in your web project as that is where the [`Styles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.styles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) static class exists. After that you need to ensure that the namespace is available in your views. To do this, edit the `web.config` that is in your `Views` folder and add the namespace

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            ....
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this line ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: thx. Should a nuget package not install all this stuff for me?! Are you saying I have to manually add the reference to the project like an animal? ;)

Comment: Nuget packages can do it sometimes, but not all do.

Comment: Adding your your above reference to root/views/web.config did it. Important to add it to web.config IN THE VIEWS FOLDER. thx. I do find it strange the nuget package doesn't do this?!

Comment: Actually, you can use the main web.config if you like, you just need to add the above into it. The file inside the views folder essentially inherits from the main config. As for why it isn't auto added, who can say apart from Microsoft. I checked the Nuget package and it certainly doesn't auto add. (pro tip: download the .nupkg file and rename it to .zip so you can look inside!)

Comment: Thanks - seems neater in the nested web.config but good to know. i can only imagine it's an oversight by MS.

Comment: Well it's possible they made an active decision to not do it (performance perhaps as it means there's another namespace to search when compiling the razor file) or maybe config transforms didn't exist when Nuget was first available?

Comment: It's a core reason to include that namespace - last updated n 2014 - they really should make this change now IMHO anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some issues make a return years later.

In my case this was there from the start:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            ....
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this line ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I had two css files, same root folder, but from there in different folders.
If referenced both in the bundle (which worked quite fine in development and example):

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

It just did not work on the QA and eventually on the production environment. I still do not know why.

I split them up in separate bundles and then referenced them as such in the _layout.cshtml.

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqui").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bstr").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```